# Data type conversion in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have string type field(Date_) which contains date like this format
**Date_**
20-05-2015
21-05-2015
22-05-2015
I want to convert this string type fields into date type field with its actual format.
I want to do this in **"JavaScript Modified Step"**.

Comment: I get this Date Field from previous step(Text File Input Step) and need final output in PostgreSQL table.(Table Output Step) Pentaho

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var dates = '20-05-2015 21-05-2015 22-05-2015'.split(' ').map(function(date) {
   date = date.split('-');
   // Date accept date in format MM-DD-YYYY
   return new Date(date[1] + '-' + date[0] + '-' + date[2]);
});
```

Comment: Bro I want to do this in Pentaho (Modified Java Script step).its not working there.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/24th3sah%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) might be useful. the regex can use parts of it self to rearrange dates.

Javascript Dates need to be in a  particular format. eg. MM-dd-yyyy.

so

```
function transformTestDate()
{
    var reg = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/g;
    var dateStr = '20-05-2015 21-05-2015 22-05-2015';
    return dateStr.replace(reg, '$2-$1-$3');  
// outputs 05-20-2015 05-21-2015 05-22-2015
}
```

That will transform your dates to the right format.
Then you will need to loop through them and get Date objects like @jcubic 's answer

```
function getDatesFromTestString()
{
    var dateStr = transfromTestDate();
    var dateArr = dateStr.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0,l = dateArr.length; i < l; i++)
        dateArr[i] = new Date(dateArr[i]);
    return dateArr;
    /*returns [Wed May 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time), 
    Thu May 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time),
    Fri May 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)]*/
}
```

gives you an array of dates

> **Note:**I have shown output in json format